# Speeding up script to flag nodes within 100 feet of segments using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, performance, code-review

I'm working with two datasets, attempting to flag when an intersection is within 100 feet of a network subset. There are over 40,000 intersections and my network is ~ 1400 segments.

The problem with the SQL script below (that I think works), is that the runtime is far too long. I'm fairly new to PostGIS and feel there is likely a faster way to do this. Basically, I'd like the each intersection (row) to have a 1 or 0 where 1 indicates the presence of a network segment within 100 feet.

Anyway to speed this up?

```
UPDATE intersections g
SET facility_flag =
      CASE
      WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM network_subset d
        WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(g.geom,
          ST_BUFFER(d.geom, 100))
      )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END
    ;
```

Comment: can't validate right now so no answer, but you should be able to do `UPDATE intersections AS g SET facility_flag = EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM network_subset AS d WHERE ST_DWithin(g.geom, d.geom, 100) )::INT`, assuming your geometries are projected in a CRS with feet as units. even if the cast doesn't work, `ST_DWithin` on indexed columns is the way to go here.

Comment: Cool cool, thank you. I'll try this out. Oh and yes, tables indexed on geom..

Comment: 25.1 seconds - thank you

Comment: @ThingumaBob you should probably add that as an answer. The combination of EXISTS and ST_Dwithin does the work here. I wonder if a LATERAL JOIN with LIMIT 1 would also work, though, I suspect, the need to also use ST_DWithin would result in a similar runtime.

Comment: @JohnPowell hm, probably, but maybe more since you'd need to convert to 0 if the join yields no result. but you're right, let me write up an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As per my comment above:*

Better use `ST_DWithin` for proximity searches:

```
UPDATE intersections AS g
  SET facility_flag = EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   network_subset AS d
    WHERE ST_DWithin(g.geom, d.geom, 100)
  )::INT
;
```

This assumes your data is projected in a CRS with feet as unit.

Here, the *Boolean* result of `EXISTS` is (explicitly) cast to `INT`. `EXISTS` will stop execution of its query when it hits the first positive comparison.

---

Make sure you have spatial indexes in place, and run standard table maintenance (`VACUUM ANALYZE <table>;`) before executing the `UPDATE`.

For *very* large tables (hundreds or thousands of times the size of yours) it can be beneficial to actually create a new table with the update logic implemented instead of an `UPDATE`. A `LATERAL JOIN`, as stated by @JohnPowell, might be the way to go then.

Comment: isn't an update query, in a way like a lateral? would there really be a boost in performance using lateral on a new table creation?

Comment: @ziggy technically they can be very similar, but in terms of database transactions, an `UPDATE` is generally a very costly operation (needless to say, it also adds itself to the overall workflow); I haven't completely thought this through, but when creating a table anew, the `LATERAL JOIN` would create a more performant query plan than a `DISTINCT...INNER JOIN` due to it stopping execution when it reaches the `LIMIT [1]` condition; however, it is very well possible to use an `EXISTS` here as well (it generally beats any `JOIN` in performance)